# Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762 Message: [ERROR] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 37, Size: 37

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

```
String str1,str2,str3;
String[] inInvoiceLine= new String [36];
inInvoiceLine = Col1.split(","); 
if (rowNum == 1)
 {
   outInvStartDt = inInvoiceLine[0];
  outInvEndDt = inInvoiceLine[1]; 
} 
else if (rowNum == 2)
{
 for( int i = 0; i < inInvoiceLine.length - 1; i++)  
{
names.add(inInvoiceLine[i].trim());}}
else if( rowNum >= 3 && rowNum <= 4)
{
 for( int i = 0; i < inInvoiceLine.length - 1; i++)  
{
str1=(inInvoiceLine[i].trim());
str2=names.get(i);
str3=str2.concat(str1);
names.set(i,str3);
}
}
 else if( rowNum > 4 )
 {
    for( int i = 0; i < inInvoiceLine.length - 1; i++) 
{    
Invoice_Beg_Date=outInvStartDt ;
Invoice_End_date=outInvEndDt ;
      switch (i) 
{
        case 0:  outCarrier = inInvoiceLine[i].trim();
                 break;
        case 1:  outContract = inInvoiceLine[i].trim();
                 break;
        case 2:  outGroup = inInvoiceLine[i].trim();
                 break;
        default: outName = names.get(i);
                outValue = inInvoiceLine[i].trim();


                 generateRow();  the fixed columns.
                 break;
      }  

    } 
}
rowNum++;
```

hi All,
 I am getting the title error in java transformation,  Source is a comma separated ,First row is reading the dates, row 2,3 and 4 will concatenation tho the fields and rest the values please help.

Comment: Looks like your source file is having more than 36 fields. Could you check the source file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the array size to the maximum number of fields (no. of commas + 1) that can come from source file. For example, if there are a max of 50 commas, then change the array declaration to:

```
String[] inInvoiceLine= new String [51];
```

If the no. of commas are arbitary, and you cannot decide how many will come beforehand, you can dynamically create the array without specifying it's size. You can change the below two lines

```
String[] inInvoiceLine= new String [36];
inInvoiceLine = Col1.split(",");
```

to the following

```
String[] inInvoiceLine = Col1.split(",");
```

This would dynamically create the array without having to worry about how many commas are present in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
It worked. but I have another question .in the above code if you see I am trimming and concatenating the fields.
example: for the rownum2,3 and 4 if the field names are like 'totalfeecount', I need to put the space between each word 'total fee count'. 
what I need to add in the above code to achieve this.

else if( rowNum >= 3 && rowNum <= 4)
{
 for( int i = 0; i < inInvoiceLine.length - 1; i++)  
{
str1=(inInvoiceLine[i].trim());
str2=names.get(i);
str3=str2.concat(str1);
names.set(i,str3);
}
I am guessing this is where i need to give the space option to get the o/p. please help.
```